# How to determine if one date is before another

Tags: python

I have a date in the format "2011-06-24", and a list of other date strings in the same format.  For each string in the list, I want to determine if that date is in the past, compared to "2011-06-24".  Is there a way to do this easily in python?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What is the problem here? Since the dates are obviously in ISO notation you can perform a standard comparison of the dates as strings here...

Comment: Why was this not obvious?  I figured with dates rolling over it would be an issue, but no.. Thanks

Comment: why is this still accepted answer? this is a very poor quality answer compared to others available on thread.

Answer (score 53):

```
>>> "2011-06-24" > "2010-06-23"
True

>>> "2011-06-24" > "2012-06-25"
False
```

Comment: This is so obviously wrong.... ????  "2000" > "1900" -> true, "2000" > "19000" -> true.

Comment: @BryanGrace The answer is based on the OP's assumption that the two dates are in ISO format and obviously does not work for any arbitrary string.

Comment: the OP never mentioned ISO (YYYY-MM-DD).  That's your assumption.  The format could easily be interpreted (blank-blank-blank).

Comment: @BryanGrace It's not my assumption, it's in the question: _I have a date in the format "2011-06-24", and a list of other date strings in the same format_. In any case, SO is  community-driven, so you can add your own answer or edit this one if you think it's wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, see [datetime comparison](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) in the python docs:

Comment: Sorry, nonsense answers. No need to convert dates in ISO notation here into datetime instances

Comment: This works, but in this particular case comparing as strings is easier and just as effective.

Answer (score 0):

And if you wanted to use also the time part of datetime, then rest assured that the same simple string comparisons can be used for time strings as well (tested in python 3.8):

```
assert("07:20:18.273" == "07:20:18.273")
assert("07:20:18.274" > "07:20:18.273")
assert("07:20:18.273" < "07:20:18.274")
assert("07:20:17.273" < "07:20:18.273")
assert("07:19:18.273" < "07:20:18.273")
assert("06:20:18.273" < "07:20:18.273")
```